# What exactly does 'authenticated' mean for wp_ajax_nopriv?

Tags: ajax

When building AJAX functionality for WP, I've always thought 'wp_ajax_nopriv' was meant for non-admin users. But now I have gone and read the documentation and it says it is for non 'authenticated' users.

So now I am confused a little bit since WP does not, by default, provide an AJAX url for the frontend.

So when they say 'authenticated' users do they mean ANY user who has logged in or just the admin when referring to the wp_ajax functionality?

Answer (score 1):

*Authenticated* here means according to the [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) function, i.e. if the user is logged in or not, no matter the user role.

This part from the `admin-ajax.php` file, explains it all:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        /**
         * Fires authenticated AJAX actions for logged-in users.
         *
         * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
         * refers to the name of the AJAX action callback being fired.
         *
         * @since 2.1.0
         */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
} else {
        /**
         * Fires non-authenticated AJAX actions for logged-out users.
         *
         * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
         * refers to the name of the AJAX action callback being fired.
         *
         * @since 2.8.0
         */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, I guess you mean [this Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)). I just updated it to hopefully make it more clear what it means to be unauthenticated. @LeeLoftiss

Comment: WOW! That's cool. Thanks for maintaining these things.